# Flash Builder 4.5 - Preloading self w/ factoryClass creates second SWF?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 to create what's needs to be a single SWF project, and I'm running into issues with allowing the main SWF to preload itself.

I know about using the meta `factoryClass` to allow for this kind of preloading, but every time I publish I'm now seeing it create a new SWF for the preloader class as well as the main class.

I swear I've used this approach in the past and never had the second file. Is this no longer the way to be doing things? Would you suggest an alternative, or is there a simple fix?

For your reference, my code is this:

```
[Frame(factoryClass="main.site.view.MainPreloader")]
```

And the website I used for reference is this:

http://flassari.is/tag/factoryclass/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure you don't have your preloader class set as an application class in your project properties, only your main class. Any class marked as an application class will cause an additional swf to be created.

Comment: Thanks! Is this a new setting for FB 4.5? I've never run into the issue before.

Comment: I believe it was in FB 4 but I'm not sure about before that. The only time I ever use that feature is when I'm doing a Flash Professional project and do want it to generate multiple swfs, where my project has multiple document classes in it.